# Dynamically wrapping text around multiple UIImageView

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uikit

In the iPad application Pages, the user can manually enter text and place images/other media on the page- making the text flow dynamically around the media. As an example, see [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vz6Qj.jpg). I also believe Apple said they're not making any use of undocumented APIs, and any developer could theoretically recreate an app like Pages.

How can I recreate this within my app?

It doesn't seem like the [CTFrame class](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/CTFrameRef/Reference/reference.html) has any mechanism for this kind of wrapping with UIImageViews/UIWebViews/etc., and my knowledge of the Cocoa APIs is a bit limited, so I'm not sure where to look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `CTFramesetterCreateFrame` function has a `path` argument that you can use to wrap text around objects.

Basically, you will have to construct a path that contains the total area that is to be filled with text, subtracting the areas that should be left free (your images).