# How to wrap text around image

Tags: ios, uitextview, core-text, word-wrap

I have a UIImageView and a UITextView, and I wish to wrap the UITextView around the image that I have, exactly as it is done using Microsoft Word using the Wrapping Style -> Square, which is found when you right click on the image Format Picture -> Layout

note that I only wish to use a UITextView, and I have no problem using CoreText

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [CTFrame](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Carbon/Reference/CTFrameRef/Reference/reference.html) classes, along with related class [CTFrameSetter](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Carbon/Reference/CTFramesetterRef/Reference/reference.html), to create a path around the image and wrap the text.

Here is a related article: http://blog.amyworrall.com/post/11098565269/text-wrap-with-core-text

And related SO question/answer: [Dynamically wrapping text around multiple UIImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7047231/dynamically-wrapping-text-around-multiple-uiimageview)